# Button doesn't work in Chrome if includes icon

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have a dropdown menu button, but when it includes some icon, it doesn't work properly in Chrome. Works only if I click on the edges of the button. Other browsers works fine. I'm using Awesome Font icons and have more similar buttons, which all works, but not this one. Is it CSS fault?

```
  <div class="dropdown">
            <button onclick="dropMenu()" class="dropbtn">
                  <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <div id="drop-menu" class="dropdown-content">
                    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                    <a href="#">Link 2</a>                        
            </div>                
    </div>
```

JS

```
function dropMenu() {document.getElementById("drop-menu").classList.toggle("show");  

window.onclick = function(event) { 
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
  for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
    var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
    if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
   }
  }
 }
}
```

CSS

```
.dropdown {
float: left;
padding-left: 1%;    
position: relative;
display: inline-block;}

.dropbtn {
font-size: 100%;
border: none;
outline: none;    
padding: 13px;
background-color: yellow;
width: 45px;
font-family: inherit;
margin: 0;
display: none;}

.dropbtn:hover, .dropbtn:focus {
background-color: grey;}

.dropbtn:hover {
cursor: pointer;    
background-color: grey;}

.dropdown-content {
display: none;
position: absolute;
background-color: grey;
min-width: 250px;
z-index: 1;}

.dropdown-content a {
float: none;
color: white;
padding: 5px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
text-align: left;}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
background-color: grey;}

.show {
display: block;}

.fa-bars {
color: white;}
```

Comment: Please post html of your dropdown as well. This part of your snippet works for me.See https://jsfiddle.net/fps4dm5d/

Comment: Have you tried setting a lower index for the icon?

Comment: @YaminiChhabra  It's only <div> with <a> hrefs...
k1dev   Yes I did, nothing changes..
Thanks fou your effort guys :)